# Kpfonts-otf: Biggl( is not the same size as Biggr)

Tags: unicode-math, kpfonts

Kpfonts-otf: Biggl( is not the same size as Biggr)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \Biggl( \Biggr)
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you compile with xelatex. Can you compile with lualatex?

Comment: Yes I compile with xelatex as I need fontspec and ctex which is better on xelatex, I mainly use Chinese.

Comment: Can you compile LuaLaTeX? You can use fontspec with LuaLaTex as well as you can do with xelatex. If you compile with LuaLaTex you will not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Windows and Lualatex now, and it will take several minutes to generate font database. Please be patient...

Answer (score 1):

Using Lualatex to compile return the same size:

[image]

Comment: Even if lualatex can correct it, it looks like an bug in the font. You should report that to the font maintainer.

Comment: On the other hand, using `kpfonts` instead of `kpfonts-otf` can correct it too.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher Bug found. Will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thank @DanielFlipo for your support!  Another question is can you redefine `\varphi` and `\varepsilon` too when using glyph variant `cv06` and `cv03` (and all the others alike), that is, exchange the `\xxx` and the `\varxxx`.